# Changing case within quoted text

Tags: syntactic-analysis, citation

I'm familiar with the convention that square brackets may be used within quoted text to indicate *word[s]* that aren't actually present *[in that exact form]* in the original. It's often necessary where the original uses a pronoun, but you want your citation to identify the context-specific proper noun, for example.

My question here includes the closely related usage whereby the square brackets indicate *optional [additional] text*. I'm familiar with this convention in the context of programming syntax, where [**dir** [Drive:][Path][FileName]](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true) means that any or all of the elements **Drive, Path, Filename** can be omitted.

But I was a bit confused by [a recent ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/132143/2637) using square brackets to indicate that a lowercase letter in the original text had been changed to uppercase...

> [D]uctility is a solid material's ability to deform under tensile stress

My natural inclination was to see the [D] as indicating an optional letter (i.e. - the word could be written as either **ductile** or **uctile**). So what I want to know is:

> Is the *square brackets = case change* convention [still] valid, and if so is it under threat from the [later?] *square brackets = optional material* convention?

Comment: I'm most surprised at your confusion—this use of square brackets is extremely common in quoted texts in my experience. I am, quite honestly, baffled that you have not come across it before. On the other hand, I cannot recall coming across the optional text usage in quotes. If additional (usually explanatory) text is added in brackets, it will usually be explicitly stated by adding ‘ed.’ or ‘emphasis mine’ or something like that.

Comment: @Janus: If I read a [citation from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eratosthenes) saying *[Eratosthenes] was the first person to use the word "geography" in Greek*, that seems normal to me. Perhaps I need to get out more and spend time with typesetters (or stay in more and read the fruits of their labours, but it would seem odd to me to read *Eratosthenes is known for many things, not least that "[h]e was the first person to use the word 'geography'"*. I don't see the case switch is worth highlighting.

Comment: ...and I'm sure you don't mean to imply you've never seen usages like my **word[s]** above (where the extra **s** is "optional additional text/characters", indicating that I don't want to be tied to either singular or plural).

Answer (score 1):

MLA Style (don't ask me!) is the first guide I've found that advocates the practice (see [How to Quote and How to Cite](http://staff.hartdistrict.org/dmoeller/How%20to%20Quote%20and%20How%20to%20Cite.ht)  ):

> Find a quotation that you can lift from the middle of a sentence and
>   place at the beginning of your quotation. By so doing, you’ll use
>   square brackets to indicate a lower case letter rewritten as a capital
>   letter. Example: “[H]e runs the risk of being physically banned by the
>   father,” admits Freud (65).

I still use it if I'm in the mood. If I feel a passage needs serious editing but believe I'm only clarifying, or correcting grammar, I usually put (tidied) after the quote and allow readers to check against the original.

Comment: the "How to Quote and How to Cite" link is broken.

Comment: Here is a replacement link, an answer given by PamPerdue at [askville.amazon.com](http://askville.amazon.com/purpose-square-brackets-single-letter-%5BT%5Dhe-%5BH%5De/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=50815124):'[S]quare brackets are used to indicate an editorial change, i.e. they indicate that a quotation was changed for clarity or grammar. The changes must be trivial and not change the meaning.' This is in answer to the same question as given here about the lower- to upper-case change when giving a reasonable part-quote.